# mysqldump from php script safety

Tags: php, mysql

If I do `shell_exec('mysqldump DATABASE_NAME')` from a php script, is there any danger?

Is there a way to get this to work in Windows?

I am going to use mysqldump for database backup from a web page

Also should I do `set_time_limit(0)` when running this?

Comment: If it can be used to access the server in any way. Do I need to escape anything like sql injections?

Comment: really not making much sense

Comment: If I have user submitted parameters such as $hostname, $username, $password do I need to escape these when using shell_exec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, there is danger: If database name comes from an untrusted source hackers could try to inject shell commands in the database name. For example:

```
$dbname = 'test; cat /etc/shadow';
```

might being used to obtain user names and encrypted passwords from the system (depends on the system)..

To avoid that, you should use `escapeshellarg()` to quote the database name (and possible other arguments):

```
shell_exec('mysqldump ' . escapeshellarg($database_name));
```

---

`set_time_limit()` isn't required if you are following my hints [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20665609/memory-requirements-for-mysqldump-from-php-script/20665662#20665662)

---

Needless to say, that you'll have to secure the page using login.