# Memory requirements for mysqldump from php script

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following script which works great for database backup. But will I ever run into memory issues for very large databases?

```
//Set large amount of memory to prevent fatal errors and don't let it timeout
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
set_time_limit(0);

$database = escapeshellarg($this->db->database);
$db_hostname = escapeshellarg($this->db->hostname);
$db_username= escapeshellarg($this->db->username);
$db_password = escapeshellarg($this->db->password);

$backup_command = "/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump -h $db_hostname -u $db_username -p$db_password $database";
$dump_output = shell_exec($backup_command);

force_download('database.sql', $dump_output);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would not use `shell_exec()`. Use `passthru()` instead, it will not require extra memory as it passes mysqldump's output untouched to PHP's output:

```
// set appropriate headers for download ...  
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="download.sql"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');

// then directly output using passthru()
passthru('/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump -h $db_hostname -u $db_username -p$db_password $database"');
```

However, this solution will not being able to set the `Content-Length` header as the size of output is unknown for PHP. In most cases it should be OK and you can live with that. (phpmyadmin does the same)

---

Using `passthru()` even `set_time_limit()` isn't required here (unless your server runs Windows(!)). From the [documenation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php):

> Note:    The set_time_limit() function and the configuration directive max_execution_time only affect the execution time of the script itself. Any time spent on activity that happens outside the execution of the script such as system calls using system(), stream operations, database queries, etc. is not included when determining the maximum time that the script has been running. This is not true on Windows where the measured time is real.

Comment: See my updated question. I really want to use passthru but I have some technical limitations. Can you see away around it?

Comment: I can't see the restriction. First select the proper path. Then call `passthru`. Using `if($output)` is really fragile. Why not using `if(is_executable($path_to_mysqldump))` ?

Comment: That should work. How can I give an error message if they all fail? Since I already set headers I am kind of stuck.

Comment: send the headers only if you are sure the path was found.

Comment: One more issue. If the path is executable but fails because it is not really the right executable (multiple mysql installs on machine) what would the status code be? I seemed to get a 2 back if it fails and a 0 if it works. Is there a list somewhere for status codes?

Comment: Ok that validates my thoughts. Do you see the problem though. 1. validates it is an executable. 2. Set headers. 3. Found out there was an error. 4. To late to set headers again

Comment: Don't understand, you asked for a list of error codes, I sent that list. What are your thoughts?

Comment: The problem is if I get an error code from passthru, it is too late to change the headers and the user would never know there was an error unless they looked in the file

Comment: Maybe I should mention, that as long as no output came from `mysqldump` you could still overwrite the headers, even if they already have been sent, because if the same header appears multiple times in HTTP the most recent value will being used by the client. However, you need to redirect mysqldump error messages to a file for that : ` &2 > error.txt` ... This might be a pain on windows...

Comment: I think I got everything working as expected. I updated my post with what you helped me come up with. Does the header stuff make sense? Thank you very much!

Comment: Looks nearly perfect now :) .. Just one thing, don't forget the error redirection: `mysqldump ... 2>> export.errors.log`  (or even `/dev/null`) .. Otherwise the error messages may produce output, and you can't rewrite the headers anymore. Also, as I said, this is a problem on windows because the "shell" (cmd.exe) supports no redirection..

Comment: It is very important for this to work on windows so I can't do that. Also, do you know the reason why mysqldump (without the path) doesn't work on 2 servers I have tested? Is this a php config? Also what are some other common paths for mysqldump?

Comment: is_executable() returns false for "C:\Program Files\PHP Point of Sale Stack\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe" so I am just going to add to check for the file extension ending in .exe. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: I got is_executable() to return TRUE, but I had to do a hack to run the mysqldump command correctly. See the edit above. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure. Seems so, if it is working :).. Btw, you should rollback all the edits, as having the solution present in the question makes no sense for SO ;)

Comment: I have rolled back question and answered the question with the final solution.

Answer (score 1):

Final solution based on comments/discussion:

```
function do_mysqldump_backup()
{
    //Set large amount of memory to prevent fatal errors and don't let it timeout

    ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
    set_time_limit(0);

    $mysqldump_paths = array('C:\Program Files\PHP Point of Sale Stack\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe',  //Windows
    '/Applications/phppos/mysql/bin/mysqldump', //Mac
    '/opt/phppos/mysql/bin/mysqldump',  //Linux
    '/usr/bin/mysqldump', //Linux
    '/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump', //Linux
    '/usr/local/bin/mysqldump', //Linux
    '/usr/mysql/bin/mysqldump'); //Linux

    $database = escapeshellarg($this->db->database);
    $db_hostname = escapeshellarg($this->db->hostname);
    $db_username= escapeshellarg($this->db->username);
    $db_password = escapeshellarg($this->db->password);

    $success = FALSE;
    foreach($mysqldump_paths as $mysqldump)
    {

        if (is_executable($mysqldump))
        {
            $backup_command = "\"$mysqldump\" --host=$db_hostname --user=$db_username --password=$db_password $database";

            // set appropriate headers for download ...  
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="php_point_of_sale.sql"');
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
            header('Pragma: public');

            $status = false; 
            passthru($backup_command, $status);
            $success = $status == 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!$success)
    {
        header('Content-Description: Error message');
        header('Content-Type: text/plain');
        header('Content-Disposition: inline');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        die(lang('config_mysqldump_failed'));   
    }
}
```